# Changing a System.Windows.Media.Imaging.ImageSource Image size/resolution?

Tags: c#, image

I have an image source of type System.Windows.Media.Imaging.ImageSource and I was wondering how I could get its resolution/size as well as modify the actual source data to change the file size and image dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast it to `BitmapSource` and then access those properties.

```
if (theImage.ImageSource is BitmapSource)
{
    BitmapSource bitmap = (BitmapSource)theImage.ImageSource;
    int width = bitmap.Width;
}
```

[Here is more info on the BitmapSource class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx)

Comment: will that get the size of the image as it is in its compressed form?

Comment: Give it a try and have a look at the properties. By "size" do you mean in bytes or the dimensions?